# Для чего странице гугл 2000 года нужен объект на странице?

Tags: javascript, html

[Heart](http://www.google.com/heart/feature_cons.html). И для чего нужен этот скрипт?

```
<script>
    new gweb.analytics.AutoTrack({profile: 'UA-12481063-1'});
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это счётчик Гугл Аналиткс. Он нужен для сбора статистических данных.

Answer (score 1):

Отслеживание сайта с помощью Google Analytics. Может старая версия скрипта.

Answer (score 1):

//www.google.com/js/gweb/analytics/autotrack.js
Это сервис для сбора статистики google